# How to override compareTo (Java)

Tags: java, comparable

I'm a beginner in programming and I have two classes. First class is:

```
public class User implements Comparable<User>
```

with field `int age`, constructor and overrided method of interface Comparable:

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(User user) {
        return user.age >= age ? -1 : 0;
    }
```

Second class is
`public class SortUser` with a method to make a Set collection from a List:

```
public Set<User> sort(List<User> list) {
        Set<User> result = new TreeSet<>();
        for (User user : list) {
            result.add(user);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It seems to me that all `User` objects in a Set should be sorted, but when I made a List with 3 `User` objects...

```
 User a = new User(1);
 User b = new User(2);
 User c = new User(3);
 List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list.add(c);
 list.add(a);
 list.add(b);
```

(Now the list's order is: `312`)
...and created a `Set` (`TreeSet`) from that list:

```
SortUser sortUser = new SortUser();
Set<User> set = sortUser.sort(list);
```

At the end I have a `set` with that order: `13`, it means that only two objects are in the `set`. What is going wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't sort it by adding it to a set. Just call `sort` on the list.

Comment: You can't have a sorted Set. Sets are unordered collections. A sort() method needs to either sort a List (or other ordered collection) in place, or return a List.

Comment: @chrisdowney Well, technically you *can* have an ordered set. You just have to make sure that the specific implementation supports it. Its very possible to write an ordered set implementation.

Comment: compareTo must return -1, 0 +1 .  good practice is to rethink hashCode() and equals()

Comment: @Carcigenicate is correct. Consider the standard java.util.TreeSet - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html  That's literally an ordered set implementation.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, true, but missing the point - the method returns a Set<User> so the calling code cannot assume it's ordered.

Comment: @chrisdowney I'm just saving against "you can't have an ordered set". I believe that's a misleading comment. I agree with your point though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I see you have wrong implementation of compare method. Could you update it to?

```
@Override
public int compareTo(User user) {
  return Integer.compare(age, user.age);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with the `TreeSet` is unnecessary. I'm not sure they're guaranteed to have certain ordering when iterated.

Just replace your sort method with

`Collections.sort(list)`

And my guess as to why an element is being dropped is your `compareTo` method never returns a `1` in any case, so elements are always considered to be less than or equal to other elements, which is probably screwing with the `TreeSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below methodology

In case of string.

```
    public static Comparator<Employee> NameComparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return e1.getName().compareTo(e2.getName());
    }
};
```

In case of Integer values

```
public static Comparator<Employee> SalaryComparator = new Comparator<Employee>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee e1, Employee e2) {
        return (int) (e1.getSalary() - e2.getSalary());
    }
};
```

Comment: It's not a good way, when there is a possibility of one of the argument being negative. However in case of salary, i suppose there are checks there which doesn't let the salary be negative.

Answer (score 0):

User class

```
 public class User implements Comparable<User>{
  int age;
  User(int age){age=age;}
  @Override
  public int compareTo(User user) {
    return this.age >= age ? -1 : 0;
  }
 }
```

prepare list

```
   User a = new User(1);
   User b = new User(2);
   User c = new User(3);
   List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add(c);
  list.add(a);
  list.add(b);
```

for sorting

```
 Set<User> list1 = new TreeSet(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new User(3));
        list.add(new User(1));
        list.add(new User(2));
        Collections.sort(list);
        list.forEach(el -> System.out.println(el.age));
    }
}

class User implements Comparable<User> {
    int age;

    User(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(User user) {
        return this.age >= user.age ? -1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to add an explanation about your answer

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```java
@Override
public int compareTo(User user) {
  if (this == user){
     return 0;
  }
  if (user != null){
     return this.age.compareTo(user.getAge())
  }
}
```